# modulo of a certain number and printing the answer in division statement

Tags: modulo

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num;
    cout<<"Number: ";
    cin>>num;
    int answer;
    answer = num%2;
    cout<<"\n"<<answer;
}
```

i have the problem of printing the answer in my division statement.

Comment: What about simply using [`std::bitset::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string)? Also note there's no need for recurstion to do this.

Comment: As a general hint, always try to initialise variables rather than leaving them in some "not-ready" state. For `int num`, this is not feasible here, but your other variable can be initialised very concisely as `int answer = num%2`. It makes your code easier to read, less error-prone and allows for more `const` variables.

Comment: You have completely changed the question now, which renders the given answers useless.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your recursive function, display output at time of unwinding i.e. after recursive calls

```
void DecimalToBinary(int n){
    int r;
    if (n != 0) 
    {
        r = n%2;
        DecimalToBinary(n/2); // recurse
        cout <<r; // Then simple print r, as its either 0 or 1
    }
   // Your else if is not stopping the recursion and its not required
}
```

Comment: your answer does not fit the question.

Comment: @helloguyzzz Well, fortunately Stackoverflow.com has [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24979184/revisions), you just change your post by seeing answers, it won't help you. It really annoys. Please post a new question if you have other doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function instead of your's-

```
void DecimalToBinary(int n){

    static int i=31; //(i=31 for 32 bit integers)
    if(i>=0){
            if (n&(1<<i--)){    //if the answer in r is 1 it will print 1
                    cout<<"1";
            }
            else{
                    cout<<"0";   //if the answer in r is 0 it will print 0
            }
            DecimalToBinary(n);
    }
}
```